# How to get monitor number in multi display configuration

Tags: c, linux, x11, multiscreen

When you configure a multi display setup in Linux you can place the monitors as you wish and a single desktop canvas is created.  In a very simple example I could place two monitors, each 1920x1200, side by side to create a 3840x1200 desktop.

The problem I have is that I could have placed:

```
  Monitor 1   Monitor 2
```

or

```
  Monitor 2   Monitor 1
```

I know the desktop size and I can use `XRRGetMonitors()` to get the position of each monitor but not the number that is used in the configuration tool and I need the id number for my application.  I am sure it is simple but I haven't found a way thus far.

Can someone enlighten me please?

Comment: @jww Looks on topic to me.

Comment: @melpomene - I believe you are right. Sorry about that.

Comment: If by *"configuration tool"* you mean Xrandr, then [it](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xrandr/tree/xrandr.c) just numbers them in the order they occur in the list returned by `XRRGetMonitors()`. Otherwise, have you checked if `xrandr --listmonitors` command lists your monitors in the same order your *"configuration tool"* numbers them? (Personally, I'd use the monitor names available in the `name` Atom in the `XRRMonitorInfo` structures, to identify the displays.)

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why do you need this number for your application?

Comment: I mean the GUI configuration tool in the computer settings.  My application works in conjunction with external tools and so there needs to be correlation between the screen layouts internally and externally, names of the screens are no good plus as all screens are the same model that doesn't help.   I have checked the order that the screens are listed and it is not related to the internal number in the GUI - that is the problem!!